# Disable inheritance, next add group in root site

Tags: permissions, inheritance

I disable inheritance in site, next I add group in roote site (http://ds-spsdev06:22810). Added group, not show in site where inheritance is disable.. ?

Why is that?

Comment: Can you please be more detailed. Say, you break permission for a subsite and then adding a new group in the root site. So now the group added in the root site is not reflected in the permissions of subsite. Is this your question?

Comment: It will not show as the new settings will get only those users\groups which are available after disabled the inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have break the inheritance. You can set individual permission for that group/user using **Grant Permissions** button in ribbon.

Reference:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219771.aspx
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-survey-02D770F3-59EB-4910-A608-5F84CC297782?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
- https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/What-is-permissions-inheritance-06bb1ed1-d150-42f4-9600-fb261d4b590c

Answer (score 1):

Because inheritance is disabled, meaning it will not inherit permission changes in the parent.

Permissions are either inherited from the parent or broken. If inherited, any changes you make to the parent trickle down. If broken, changes to the parent are not reflected in the object with broken permission.

The groups created in the root will be available for use in the subsite, but aren't automatically granted any permission, because you have broken the inheritance.